# When a user submits a Google Form, can an email be generated with the submitted data?

Tags: javascript, php, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I have a Google Form where users enter the data, is there anyway I could get the data in email when the user has submitted data?

If that doesn't work I want to create my own form using(PHP or JavaScript), is there a way where i could send the data from my form to Google Form.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at 
http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/guide_events.html#Installable

section titled "More Detailed Events" ?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your second paragraph about sending the data to your Google Form, you could do it by making the post url (**action**=) attribute of your form the same where the the Google Form posts its data.  As long as your form input's have the same name it won't know where that the data isn't coming from the Google Form but rather from your site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) from [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) (using JavaScript). Here is a [code sample](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/solutions/content-signup) you can start with. Here's [another example](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/11855185) but less relevant as it's based on certain values in a cell, not a Google Forms submission.

If you end up creating your own web form, you would submit it directly to Google Sheets (where all Forms submissions go) and not Google Forms. (There's no need for both a web form *and* Google Forms.) Also in this case, instead of using Apps Script, you'd be using the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets) from your web app. Here are API quickstarts for [PHP](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) and [Node.js](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) to get started with.

Comment: Nowadays Google Sheets and Google Forms have built-in notifications. Also, beside the "solution" there is an Google Apps Script Forms add-on sample (the code is the official add-ons site).